# translating a string of words to another string of words

Tags: c++, arrays, string, function

I want a program that gets a `char[]` as input and outputs a `char[]` of the same length but that its first character is a `w` , the last one is a `f` and all the characters in between are `o`s.

If the input has size one, the output shoul be de `'w'` and if it has 2 characters it should be `wf`.

Example: "stackOverflow" => "wooooooooooof"

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <cstring>
  
  using namespace std;
 
  void translate(char human[], char dog[]); //human is input and dog is output
 
  int main()
  {
      char human[100], dog[100];
 
      cout << "Enter a string: ";
      cin.getline(human, 100);
 
      for (int i = 0; i < strlen(human); i++)
      {
          dog[i] = human[i];
      }
      dog[strlen(human)] = '\0';
 
      cout << dog << endl;
 
 
      return 0;
  }
 
 
  void translate (char human[], char dog[])
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < strlen(human); i++)
      {
          dog[i] = human[i];
      }
 
  }
```

Comment: The program compiles and whatever the user inputs like "hello" then the program will output "hello." I know I'm missing a few steps to get what I want to create. It should be outputting "wooof" instead of "hello."

Comment: your code doesn't even try to do what you expect it to do, and you never call the `translate ` function in `main`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
      for (int i = 0; i < strlen(human); i++)
      {
          if(i == 0)
          {
            dog[i] = 'w';
          }
          else if(i == (strlen(human)-1))
          {
            dog[i] = 'f';
          }
          else
          {
            dog[i] = 'o';
          }
      }
```

Comment: Note that the only useful information from human is the length of the string